# The height of a row in angular ui-grid is overridden by ui-grid CSS but I can't override the height

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using angular ui-grid v3.0.4. I have a case where I need to use a custom cell template with a button and have text below it. I see the styles in Chrome Dev tools but I don't see that ui-grid-cell, ui-grid-row or ui-grid-cell has a height set to 30px like below:

.grid1445012976265 .ui-grid-row, .grid1445012976265 .ui-grid-cell, .grid1445012976265 .ui-grid-cell .ui-grid-vertical-bar {
    height: 30px;
}

I'm loading my own stylesheet last and I override some other ui-grid CSS like input[type="text"].ui-grid-filter-input so I know that overriding it works. I have also tried commenting the other styles that I override.

In my grid definition, I set the rowHeight but it the css gets overridden by the above.

enableFiltering: true,
                rowHeight:75,
                enableRowSelection: true,

Has anyone else run into a similar issue with the ui-grid? Which css did you have to override?

If I uncheck the height: 30px; in dev tools, then the row renders correctly.

TIA
Magnus

Comment: Adding rowHeight to the definition worked for me. It will better if you can replicate the issue on plunker.

Comment: Thanks @SaiGridihar, this particular issue has been difficult to isolate and put on a plunkr unfortunately.